# Will old (+5) reputation remain in the old reputation leagues?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

Reputation leagues offer at least approximate values showing how much reputation the users had at some point in the past. For example, I can check the reputation [at the end of 2018](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/year/meta/2018-01-01), at the [end of 2017](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/year/meta/2017-01-01), etc.

I am aware of the fact that the values in the reputation leagues are not exact values of the reputation the users had at that time. For example, reputation from deleted posts and reputation lost on downvotes (of answers) is not shown in the reputation leagues. Still, it is at least reasonable approximation.

At the moment, reputation is being recalculated networkwide from +5 to +10 for upvote on a question.

**Question.** Will this change be retroactive also for reputation league, or will past reputation leagues still show reputation calculated from +5 for questions?

Comment: Presumably, everything gets recalculated, on a *per-day basis.*  That's the only way to make sure that rep caps are respected and badges are properly awarded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reputation leagues will recompute as well (should be in the next couple days or so) and will reflect the new vote value.

Comment: But will that change be retroactive, since the reputation change is retroactive? Will the rankings for past periods change?

Comment: @caleb Yes, it'll recalc from day one. Hopefully successfully.